# Motion detection of object from foreground extraction(grabcut)

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, motion-detection

I'm new to opencv python

Now, I'm doing motion detection(in webcam) of an object that I got from foreground extraction (using grabcut). I already got an object from grabcut but I don't know how to code to detect that object movement and show the movement in the webcam screen.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**here is the code for object detection with motion tracking but you need to download some external file like mobilenet model ,CentroidTracker**

````
import datetime
import imutils
import numpy as np
import csv 
# from centroidtracker import CentroidTracker
from pyimagesearch.centroidtracker import CentroidTracker
protopath = "mobilenet_ss/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt"
modelpath = "mobilenet_ss/MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel"


detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt=protopath, caffeModel=modelpath)
# detector.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_INFERENCE_ENGINE)
detector.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

fields=['new_id_detected',"total_person_count"]
filename = "person_records.csv"
  
outputlist=[]        

CLASSES = ["background", "aeroplane", "bicycle", "bird", "boat",
           "bottle", "bus", "car", "cat", "chair", "cow", "diningtable",
           "dog", "horse", "motorbike", "person", "pottedplant", "sheep",
           "sofa", "train", "tvmonitor"]

tracker = CentroidTracker(maxDisappeared=80, maxDistance=90)


def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):
    try:
        if len(boxes) == 0:
            return []

        if boxes.dtype.kind == "i":
            boxes = boxes.astype("float")

        pick = []

        x1 = boxes[:, 0]
        y1 = boxes[:, 1]
        x2 = boxes[:, 2]
        y2 = boxes[:, 3]

        area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
        idxs = np.argsort(y2)

        while len(idxs) > 0:
            last = len(idxs) - 1
            i = idxs[last]
            pick.append(i)

            xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
            yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
            xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
            yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

            w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
            h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

            overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

            idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
                                                   np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

        return boxes[pick].astype("int")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred in non_max_suppression : {}".format(e))


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project_video.mp4')

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("output/output.mp4", fourcc, 5.0, (600,337))


    fps_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    fps = 0
    total_frames = 0
    lpc_count = 0
    opc_count = 0
    object_id_list = []

    
    # dtime = dict()
    # dwell_time = dict()

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        total_frames = total_frames + 1

        (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
        #print("h,w",H,W)
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.007843, (W, H), 127.5)

        detector.setInput(blob)
        person_detections = detector.forward()
        rects = []
        for i in np.arange(0, person_detections.shape[2]):
            confidence = person_detections[0, 0, i, 2]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                idx = int(person_detections[0, 0, i, 1])

               

                person_box = person_detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                (startX, startY, endX, endY) = person_box.astype("int")
                rects.append(person_box)

        boundingboxes = np.array(rects)
        boundingboxes = boundingboxes.astype(int)
        rects = non_max_suppression_fast(boundingboxes, 0.3)

        objects = tracker.update(rects)
        for (objectId, bbox) in objects.items():
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
            x1 = int(x1)
            y1 = int(y1)
            x2 = int(x2)
            y2 = int(y2)

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            text = "ID: {}".format(objectId)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (x1, y1-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

            if objectId not in object_id_list:
                object_id_list.append(objectId)
                # dtime[objectId] = datetime.datetime.now()
                # dwell_time[objectId] = 0
            # else:
            #     curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            #     old_time = dtime[objectId]
            #     time_diff = curr_time - old_time
            #     dtime[objectId] = datetime.datetime.now()
            #     sec = time_diff.total_seconds()
            #     dwell_time[objectId] += sec

            # text = "{}|{}".format(objectId, int(dwell_time[objectId]))
            # cv2.putText(frame, text, (x1, y1-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        fps_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_diff = fps_end_time - fps_start_time
        if time_diff.seconds == 0:
            fps = 0.0
        else:
            fps = (total_frames / time_diff.seconds)

        fps_text = "FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps)
        
        cv2.putText(frame, fps_text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

        lpc_count = len(objects)
        opc_count = len(object_id_list)

        lpc_txt = "LPC: {}".format(lpc_count)
        opc_txt = "OPC: {}".format(opc_count)
        # writing to csv file  
        outputlist.append([lpc_count,opc_count])
        
            
        cv2.putText(frame, lpc_txt, (5, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.putText(frame, opc_txt, (5, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow("Application", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:  
            # creating a csv writer object  
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)   
            csvwriter.writerow(fields)
            csvwriter.writerows(outputlist)

main()```
````